# Migrate Blogger into Uni.me and integrate with Cloudflare

Tags: dns, blogger, nameservers, cloudflare

I want to add my [blogger](http://refinerypedia.blogspot.com/) DNS into [Uni.me](http://Uni.me) configuration to migrate to [refinerypedia.uni.me](http://refinerypedia.uni.me).
At the same time I want to add [Cloudflare](http://www.cloudflare.com) Nameservers to activate their services.The problem here is that [Uni.me](http://Uni.me) don't allow to use DNS and Nameservers at the same time but I must activate the two options. It gives me that error

```
You have 2 options activated!
Your setup has errors and your domain will not display/resolve correctly.
How to solve?
Make sure you have only activated either URL, Nameserver or Zone Records.
Delete one of the currently two activated options in order to avoid possible conflicts.
```

Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CloudFlare can only work with top-level domains (refinerypedia.me) when you add them to our service. That is technically a subdomain of uni.me & we wouldn't let you to add it (our service would try to add uni.me).

Comment: Actually, our system let you add the domain like that for some reason. Strange.